# Postgresql: Select first row in group by (with a twist)

Tags: postgresql

I am having a great difficulty writing SQL for the following problem:

I have a following database columns in table "answers"

```
user_id integer,
question_id integer,
session_id text,
crated_date timestamp,
correct_answer boolean
```

Now i would like to have a list of sessions and count correct and incorrect FIRST answers for every question in that session. Each user may answer the same question many times during one session, i would like to know how many questions were answered correctly/incorrecly the first time they appeared in a session. The column `created_date` determines the order of answers. The result i am trying to obtain should have the following format:

```
session_id text,
user_id integer,
questions_answered_correctly_first_time_in_session integer,
questions_answered_incorrectly_first_time_in_session integer,
questions_answered_correctly_after_first_time_in_session integer,
questions_answered_incorrectly_after_first_time_in_session integer
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure this will work, but you could give it a go:

Note, this is an on the fly constructed idea, I have not at all looked at performance, there might be some better way.

```
with first_answers as (select
        session_id,
        question_id,
        min(created_date) as created_date,
        TRUE as first_answer
    from answers
    group by session_id, question_id)
select
    first.session_id,
    first.user_id,
    sum(case when coalesce(first_answer, FALSE) and correct_answer then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when coalesce(first_answer, FALSE) and not correct_answer then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when not coalesce(first_answer, FALSE) and correct_answer then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when not coalesce(first_answer, FALSE) and not correct_answer then 1 else 0 end)
from answers left join first_answers using (session_id, user_id, created_date)
group by session_id
```